# Render Vertex Colours in Blender Internal

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, render-layers, vertex-colors

I don't like using cycles and prefer using blender internal render. So how can I render my vertex colours in Internal render. like as a material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You enable the option in the shader panel for Vertex Color Paint.[image]