# OBJ files and vertex colours

Tags: texturing, objects, blender-internal-render-engine

I would like to import a dental scan obj file. When the file is opened in windows 3d print viewer the tissue and tooth colours are visible.
When you import into blender, the colours do not show up. This may be a simple setting? Here is a photo of windows Print 3d Viewer.

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about actual per-vertex colours or textures?

Comment: These scans have vertex colours assigned in the obj files.

Comment: Have you checked that they are imported under mesh data and just not showing? Also for blender internal rendering of them, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114726/render-vertex-colours-in-blender-internal

Comment: Nothing seems to do this, a bit lost here.

Comment: Looks like the importer ignores the vertex color. Might be a similar bug to the one in the ply importer that has been fixed some time ago. https://developer.blender.org/T63227

Comment: Checked the source of the .obj importer and it doesn't seem to process vertex color at all. So technically not a bug, but a missing feature (unless this is mandatory by some standard).

Comment: Just checked, the specification of the .obj format doesn't allow vertex color, so what some software does is an extension of the format which is not conforming with the standard. I'd suggest exporting with a different format such as .ply which allows to use vertex colors and can be properly read by Blender.

Comment: Importing PLY works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`.obj` format specification](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~boulos/cs3505/obj_spec.pdf) doesn't contain any description of vertex color attributes. Some software like MeshLab or Agisoft Metashape extend the .obj format and include the vertex colors after the coordinates.

```
v 3.112696 -9.640543 15.350909 0.592157 0.517647 0.537255
```

Since it is not covered by the specification, Blender provides no ability to import vertex colors. There are other formats that *do allow* to store vertex color which can be imported into Blender, for example `.ply`.