# Dense Cloud col attribute not showing

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes, vertex-colors, point-clouds, custom-attributes

I'm using metashape agisoft to generate dense cloud from images and I exported the points in PLY and imported to blender.
then used attribute named it col to get the original color what calculated by metashape but still not showing up.
in the spread sheet the colors data is showing.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, when exporting the Point Cloud from MetaShape, the vertex color is saved (somehow), but there are the following problems:

- In the *OBJ* format, a vertex color is stored, but this format does not actually support vertex color, so Blender does not read it ([OBJ files and vertex colours](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144278/obj-files-and-vertex-colours)).
- In *PLY* format, a vertex color is stored and Blender could theoretically read it as well (but it does NOT), but that wouldn't make much sense anyway, since MetaShape doesn't seem to store correct colors here either.

The alternative is the *FBX* format. Here you also have a lot of ballast in the package, but it works. With Geometry Nodes you can read the attribute for the vertex color and you can also convert the mesh back into a point cloud.